# Python script will not output in windows command line

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, using 2.7.12 and am trying to run a very simple script that will hash a 'salt' and simple password using a DES algorithm (I know DES is outdated but this is just to learn how to generate a hash value with a salt). I have this working in the interpreter (i.e. I get the expected hash output 'HX9LLTdc/jiDE') but when I try to run it in my sublime text and/or via command line I get no errors but no output either? I know this is a simple fix but i'm having a blank as to why its not outputting the hash value in my command line after running the script? Any advice, much appreciated.

```
import passlib.hash

def createHash():

    salt = "HX"
    word = "egg"
    cryptWord = passlib.hash.des_crypt.encrypt(word, salt=salt) 
    print "DES:" + cryptWord
```

Comment: okay but do you actually _call_ `createHash` ?

Comment: Your script defines a function, `createHash`, but doesn't actually call it.

Comment: How do you call the function in the interpreter?

Comment: Many thanks, was slightly confused on the method call. Works fine now.

Comment: Many thanks, was slightly confused on the method call. Works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `createHash()` method:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    createHash()
```

Comment: Many thanks bastian, was slightly confused on the method call. Works fine now.